# Is it possible to update a GeoJSON choropleth in MapBoxGL JS without changing the geometries?

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js, choropleth

I'm visualizing a relatively large (~5MB) GeoJSON feature collection as a choropleth. Depending on user actions, I'll want to fetch some additional data from the network and re-render the choropleth. Unfortunately, this winds up being slow and janky.

Here's the code:

```
  map.addSource('blocks', {
    type: 'geojson',
    data: geojson,
  });

  map.addLayer({
    'id': 'blocks',
    'type': 'fill',
    'source': 'blocks',
    'layout': {
    },
    'paint': {
      'fill-color': [
        'interpolate',
        ['linear'],
        ['get', 'value'],
        0, '#FF0000',
        1, '#00FFFF'
      ],
      'fill-opacity': 0.8
    }
  });

  function randomValues(geojson) {
    for (const feature of geojson.features) {
      feature.properties.value = Math.random();
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('update').addEventListener('click', () => {
    randomValues(geojson);
    map.getSource('blocks').setData(geojson);
  });
```

Fully worked demo: https://bl.ocks.org/danvk/3d026ca39ed11562bb0319f0619c3460

When you click the button, the choropleth is updated with new random values. Unfortunately, this is quite slow (1-2 seconds) and janky (you can see mixed states as different parts of the choropleth update).

My assumption is that this is because Mapbox GL JS has to serialize and deserialize all the big complicated geometries of the features whenever they update. Ideally I'd like to be able to pass in just an id → color mapping when I do an update, without passing in new geometries.

Is this possible? Is the slowness explained by something else? Is it possible to smoothly update a choropleth with Mapbox GL JS?

Comment: yes, you can use a technique similar to what happens in this example https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/data-join/, but calling `map.setPaintProperty('blocks', 'fill-color', expression)` with the new styling expression you want to use based on each feature's `id`

Comment: Thanks @mollymerp! That does eliminate the need to re-serialize the geometries. Here's an [updated demo](https://bl.ocks.org/danvk/210d79658597630225663f8a9a2f73f9) using that approach. If you'd like to post an answer I'll accept. While the amount of data being updated is much smaller now, the update is still slow and jerky (you can see the map in a halfway state). Is this just an inherent limitation of Mapbox GL JS?